# Plain text email formatting issue

Tags: email, text, outlook, formatting

I am sending a Plain text email containing a report
I am padding the text with '.' so the text will align nicely
The output seems to work great in notepad++
But appears to be bad format in the email client

See the attached picture , the top is in NPP showing the correct format
The bottom is the plain text email with the broken un aligned format.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?
I tried underscore, and space, tab
it still shows a broken un aligned format..
I also saw a post on StackOverflow saying that double space at the beginning of the row will fix it, it didn't help.

Thank you!

Comment: have you used a Tab?

Comment: yes, tab was worst.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you really need to use HTML and set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property instead of plain text `Body`.

Secondly, if you want things to line up, use a fixed width font, such as Consolas. Again, you can do that if you work with HTML and can explicitly specify the font.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I am working with a legacy system that sends plain text emails,

Comment: Are you using Outlook Object Model to create the message? If yes, you can still set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property if only to expliiclty specify the font.